# Angular UI-Router templateUrls in state - .HTML or .CSHTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, angular-ui-router

I'm wondering which way is better to keep the partial HTML's in Angular UI-Router ($stateProvider) in app which is built in ASP.NET MVC

This approach (corresponds to RAZOR view from MVC)

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '/Account/Login' // corresponds to an MVC partial route
})
```

or maybe this approach:

```
.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'App/Partials/Login.html' // corresponds to an html file inside App folder (where Angular module and controllers are)
})
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches? (or whatever they are?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a matter of what your end goal is.

If you need to use MVC to take part in rendering your templates then I believe you can use the option where you target an MVC route. Your advantages here are you can render the view on the server-side before angularJS takes over. This may be important if you want to hide parts of your source. It also means you can continue using ASP.NET rendered html which may be important if you are migrating an old solution. Using Model data from ASP.NET MVC may get a little messy and you may need to bootstrap this data if you intend to use it in your client AngularJS code. You will need to remember to access any MVC Models as @Html.Raw(model) in your js scripts. I personally think this makes for a messier implementation.

If you don't need MVC rendering at all and are happy to go AngularJS all the way, you can ignore MVC routes and target the template HTML files as you've done in your second example. If you don't need MVC rendering, I'd suggest doing it this way as then you can fully utilize AngularJS and not worry about messing it up with MVC. This is the solution I use. I still use ASP.NET MVC routing, but purely for WebAPI calls as opposed to any template access. One issue with an MVCless approach is that your main page would always be present in the URL (eg. http://example.com/home.html), but you can get around this with Rewrite Rules in IIS (as I have done with my applications). Also, you wont have a Model from MVC, but you could instead use AngularJS $http and/or $resource to make async calls to a WebAPI service layer.